# Webpack UglifyJsPlugin doesn't work on OSX but does on Windows

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

When I try to compile my webpack build on OSX it gives an weird error but on Windows not, also never occurred.

errored on '{': `/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__["default"] = class {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using webpack 2, chances are that you have a dependency to some module that has the jsnext:main configuration option to provide its code as ES6 modules. In these cases, webpack 2 uses them, which works fine, until you try to use Uglify, which can't deal with ES6 code.

You're probably excluding your node_modules from Babel loading, as well you should, but for this to work, you need to tell webpack explicitly to include this jsnext:main module.

I had this problem with preact-compat and solved it like this:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/preact-compat/src')
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, that sounds about right. I made one myself and made an (awkward?) regex like so: `exclude: /node_modules\/(?!@company\/private-module)/`

Comment: yup, if you use "include" instead like in my code example, it will only use code from srcPath (change this to wherever your source files are located), pus the path to the module from node_modules that you need to "Babelize"